# Show/hide RadToolBar control using javascript

Tags: telerik

How can I show/hide the RadToolBar control using client-side javascript?

I've tried:

```
var toolBar = $find("<%=RadToolBar2.ClientID%>");
toolBar.set_visible(false);
```

and

```
var toolBar = $find("<%=RadToolBar2.ClientID%>");
toolBar.hide;
```

Doesn't work!

The HTML:

```
<telerik:RadToolBar ID="RadToolBar1" runat="server" Width="100%" OnClientButtonClicked="ToolBarClickHandler">
     <Items>
          <telerik:RadToolBarButton runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Toolbar/Search.png" Text="Search" AllowSelfUnCheck="True" CheckOnClick="True">
          </telerik:RadToolBarButton>
     </Items>
</telerik:RadToolBar>

<telerik:RadToolBar ID="RadToolBar2" runat="server" Width="100%" Visible="False">
     <Items>
          ... some buttons
     </Items>
</telerik:RadToolBar>
```

Thank you!

Comment: The first one works just fine, perhaps you could provide your html so that we may see how you have you page set up.

Comment: I have two RadToolBar controls. I have a on/off button on RadToolBar1 which shows/hides the second toolbar (RadToolBar2).

Comment: When the RadToolBar2 Visible property is set to "False", the on/off button on RadToolBar1 doesn't work. When I remove Visible="False" from the html, it works just fine. The problem is that I want to start the application with the RadToolBar2 hidden.